# Removing lines in text document that end the same

Tags: grep, sed, acl, squid

We have a script that downloads a list of domains for our squid box to block, but we keep getting warnings like the following:

```
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: You should probably remove '.artnau.com' from the ACL named 'chat_domains'
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: '.artnau.com' is a subdomain of '.css.artnau.com'
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: because of this '.css.artnau.com' is ignored to keep splay tree searching predictable
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: You should probably remove '.artnau.com' from the ACL named 'chat_domains'
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: '.chatserve.com' is a subdomain of '.eagles.chatserve.com'
2015/03/02 17:08:47| WARNING: because of this '.eagles.chatserve.com' is ignored to keep splay tree searching predictable
```

Is there any way to go through the file, and remove the subdomains from existing domains in the list?

So grab the first line and check to see if there are any other lines in the text that end with that text and remove it?

Comment: Can you post part of the file, including the lines which are conflicting?

Comment: It's a 15k line text document that just lists domain names to be blocked by squid.  Here's a link to the file: http://pastebin.com/6mLB2KfZ

Comment: Basically it would have a list like:
.artnau.com
.css.artnau.com
.chatserve.com
.eagles.chatserve.com

It would be great to (for example) to get .chatserve.com from the list and remove any other lines in the text that end with .chatserve.com (but keep the original line)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you would do it in Perl:

```
$ cat a.txt
.artnau.com
.bar.foo.example.org
.chatserve.com
.css.artnau.com
.eagles.chatserve.com
.example.com
.foo.example.org
$ cat a.txt | perl -ne 'BEGIN { my %h; } $h{$_} = ""; END { foreach (keys %h) { $orig = $_; $_ =~ s/^\..*?\./\./; print $orig if not exists $h{$_} } }' | sort > b.txt
$ cat b.txt 
.artnau.com
.chatserve.com
.example.com
.foo.example.org
```

The Perl one-liner loops through `a.txt` and adding every line to a hash named `%h`. After every line of the file is added, it goes through every key in the hash, removes the first part of the domain (the first period until the second period), and if the resulting string is not in the hash, prints it out. The output is then piped through `sort` (you can probably guess what that does) and saved to `b.txt`.

Comment: Please excuse my ugly Perl, I'm sure there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: The [useless `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html) is more offensive.

Comment: @tripleee So you're more of a [`dog`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/gutsy/man1/dog.1.html) person?

Comment: Thanks for that... is there any way of doing the action on the file it self (without creating a new file)?

Comment: Also, I need to run that command on every file called domain in a directory tree... I tried `find BL -name "domains" -print0 | xargs -0 -I file cat file | perl -ne 'BEGIN { my %h; } $h{$_} = ""; END { foreach (keys %h) { $orig = $_; $_ =~ s/^\..*?\./\./; print $orig if not exists $h{$_} } }' | sort > file2` but it  gave me one line in a file called file2.